# South Data Migration in Django

Tags: python, django, database-migration, django-south, data-migration

I want to Exclude link from a Data field.
Like, I have a model named "Profile". in the Model, there is a field named "facebook". in that field, data is saved like "https://www.facebook.com/user_name". I want to exclude the "https://www.facebook.com/" and keep only the "user_name" data.
So how I can do that with South migration?

I have made a data migration with ./manage.py datamigration , and in that migration I have changed as following
    class Migration(DataMigration):

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    "Write your forwards methods here."
    orm.Profile.objects.exclude(facebook='https://www.facebook.com/').update(facebook='')

def backwards(self, orm):
    "Write your backwards methods here."
    raise RuntimeError('Cannot reverse this migration.')
```

But, it seems that its deleting all the Data of that field.
So what should I do in order to keep only the "user_name" and exclude the     "https:/www.facebook.com/"     data?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what South is for... but if this is how you need to handle it, I'm pretty sure you can do the following (but test it on a copy first):

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    for profile in orm.Profile.objects.all():
        profile.facebook = profile.facebook.split('/')[-1]
        profile.save()
```